# CSS (Tumblr): Adding posts to pages in Tumblr account (e.g colors.tumblr.com/black)

Tags: css, blogs, tumblr

I currently have [About](http://laboumph.tumblr.com/about) and [Contact](http://laboumph.tumblr.com/contact) section. Now I would like to add News section but is it possible to add posts directly there without it showing on your blog's front page? Thank you! ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom pages which are effectively a single post and add as much content to them as you want and keep adding/editing content as you go.

The other alternative is to tag posts with 'news' and then link to those posts via the navigation.

So

```
http://your.tumblr.com/tagged/news
```

However you cannot hide these posts from your main blog without using a pretty big hack.

Comment: Probably more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Just to add to this, you could use the *redirect* option. `/news` and point it to `/tagged/news`.